# How to migrate 10GB old table to new table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, database-migration

I have re-written my website and created new fresh optimized tables. Now I want to migrate live data from old tables to new tables.

BUT there are few tables having more than **10 GB** data. So exporting it by clicking export hangs the PHPMyadmin! Is there any alternative or good approach to export it and migrate it to the new table?

I tried exporting the tables one by one. BUT it hangs the PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: You can define exporting by chunks, say X number of rows at a time.

Comment: @Martin any example?

Comment: Write a script to do it or use an existing command line utility; it'll be able to run as long as it needs to without worrying about a web UI hanging.